# Graphing Shekel's Foxhole (De-Jong's fifth) Function using pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

Please can anyone help on how to plot Foxhole function using pgfplot? The function is defined as:
0:998004
{0:002+∑ (from j = 1 to j= 25) [j + [x1 − a(1j)]^6 + [x2 −a(2j)]^6 ]^(-1)}^(-1);  x1, x2 in [−65:536; 65:536]

where a(ij)'s are entries of the following matrix

(−32 −16 0 16 32 −32 −16 ... 0 16 32

−32 −32 −32 −32 −32 −16 −16 ... 32 32 32)

The difficulty I am a facing is how to  code the matrix part in pgfplot. Sorry for the way I formatted the text, for a well formatted definition of the function and how the function's plot looks like, 
please see: 
https://www.al-roomi.org/benchmarks/unconstrained/2-dimensions/7-shekel-s-foxholes-function

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Unfortunately, we're not fans of "please do this for me", nor are we fans of "follow this link to see what I mean".  You'll have better luck if you can make this post self-contained, and show us as much of the TeX as you can (one or two terms of the sum would be nice).  Notationally, it looks like you're using `:` for a decimal separator; is that correct?  And can you create a formula for your matrix?  That may help move things along.

Comment: I copy and pasted the (pdf) details of the function but it got distorted. However, this is the latex code for displaying the details of the function (any suggestion on a better way to type set the function on this forum?) (the latex code could not be contained in one post so I divided it into two posts) :

Comment: \begin{document}
 \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{25}
 $F = \{0.002 + \sum_{j=1}^{25}[j + \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - a_ij)^6]^{-1}\}^{-1};\hspace{.05in} n= 2; \  x_i \in [{-65.536, \ 65.536}]$
  \\\\
 $(a_ij) =$
 $\begin{pmatrix}
 %rows
 -32 & -16 &  0  &  16 &  32 & 
 -32 & -16 &  0  &  16 &  32 & 
 -32 & -16 &  0  &  16 &  32 & 
 -32 & -16 &  0  &  16 &  32 & 
 -32 & -16 &  0  &  16 &  32\\

Comment: %columns
 -32 & -32 & -32 & -32 & -32 & 
 -16 & -16 & -16 & -16 & -16 & 
  0  &  0  &  0  &   0 &   0 &  
  16 & 16  & 16  &  16 &  16 & 
  32  &  32 & 32  & 32 & 32
 \end{pmatrix}$
 \\\\
 
    1 $\leq i \leq n$ \\
\end{document}

Comment: This is the pgfplot code I implemented, my problem is how to incorporate the matrix part:

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel={Foxhole Function}, %xmin = -3, xmax = 3, ymin = -2, ymax = 2
  ]
  \addplot3[surf, domain=-65.536:65.536] {(0.002 + (1 + (x + 32)^6 + (y + 32)^6)^(-1) 
    )^(-1)};
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix seems to be just a nested loop. One can implement the sum by accumulating the function in this nested loop. `pgfplots` may not be right tool for this, at least if you are as impatient as I am. Even for this rather low number of samples this takes very long.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\xdef\myf{0.02}
\foreach \X [count=\nX] in {-32,-16,0,16,32}
{\foreach \Y [count=\nY] in {-32,-16,0,16,32}
 {\xdef\myf{\myf+1/(\nX+5*(\nY-1)+(x-1*(\X))^6*(y-1*(\Y))^6)}}}
%\typeout{\myf} 
\begin{axis}[domain=-40.5:40.5,domain y=-40.5:40.5,samples=42,samples y=42]
 \addplot3[surf,z buffer=sort]{1/(\myf)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, the above latex code can be used for displaying the function details, so as to have a better understanding of the function.