# How to plot a summation of functions in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot a summation of pulses to depict binary pulses transmitted over a comms channel introducing ISI. I can plot the individual pulses by putting a \foreach loop around the \addplot command, adding one plot for each pulse as the following code shows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes.arrows,shapes.geometric,calc,decorations.markings,patterns}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Draw the user bits 
\newcommand{\userBits}[3]{
  % #1 the location west anchor of the bit array
  % #2 a base label identifying this set of bits, eg: userBits or parityBits
  % #3 the contents of the foreach loop that creates the bit array eg: a/1/0,b/1/1,c/0/2
  % The first component is part of the label for the node box created that holds the bit
  % The second component is the contents of the box that is written onto the page
  % The third component is needed for compatibility with the drawIndividualWaveforms function
  %                     it is not used in this function, but should still be there for compatibility.
  \coordinate(O) at ($#1$);
  \foreach\i/\j/\k in {#3}{
    \node [bitBox,fill=blue!15] at (O)(#2\i){\j};
    \coordinate(O) at (#2\i.0);
  }
}


\newcommand{\drawIndividualWaveforms}[3]{
  % #1 the location of the plot of individual waveforms
  % #2 a label for this node
  % #3 the contents of the for loop holding 3 components such as a/+/0:
  %    first component is a sublabel for this particular bit
  %    second component is the value of the bit either + or -
  %    third component is a k index indicating the delay of this wave pulse.
  \node at ($#1$){\tikz{
  \begin{axis} [axis lines =left,
      width=6cm, height=2.7cm,
      xtick=\empty,xticklabel=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,
      axis x line = middle,
      ymin=-1.1, ymax=1.1,
      xmin=0, xmax=7,
    ]
    \foreach\i/\j/\k in{#3}{
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\j}{+}}{
        \addplot[domain=\k-1:\k+1,
          samples=21,] {exp(-(x-\k)*(x-\k)*4)}; %{0.5*cos(180*x-180*\k)+0.5};
      }{
        \addplot[domain=\k-1:\k+1,
          samples=21,] {-exp(-(x-\k)*(x-\k)*4)}; %{-0.5*cos(180*x-180*\k)-0.5};
      }
    }
  \end{axis}      
  }};
}
\newcommand{\drawCombinedWaveforms}[3]{
  % #1 the location of the plot of individual waveforms
  % #2 a label for this node
  % #3 the contents of the for loop holding 3 components such as a/+/0:
  %    first component is a sublabel for this particular bit
  %    second component is the value of the bit either + or -
  %    third component is a k index indicating the delay of this wave pulse.
  \node at ($#1$){\tikz{
  \begin{axis} [axis lines =left,
      width=6cm, height=2.7cm,
      xtick=\empty,xticklabel=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,
      axis x line = middle,
      ymin=-1.1, ymax=1.1,
      xmin=0, xmax=7,
    ]
    \def\k{5}
    \addplot[domain=0:7,samples=101]{
      \foreach\i/\j\k in {#3}{
        +exp(-(x-\k)*(x-\k)*4)
      }
    };
  \end{axis}      
  }};
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\tikzset{>=stealth,
  signalLabel/.style={text centered,font=\scriptsize,above,align=center},
  boundingBox/.style={use as bounding box},
  channelModule/.style={scale=.7,draw,top color=blue!30,align=center,inner sep=0.25cm,minimum height=1.2cm,node distance=0.75cm,minimum width=1.5cm},
  bitBox/.style={anchor=180,draw,font=\scriptsize,inner sep=0,minimum width=0.33cm,minimum height=0.4cm}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\channelSubFrame}[2]{
  % Create a subframe for the animation demonstrating the parity check ENCODING process
  % #1 Flag for the contenst of the channel box. 0: Channel. 1: Raised cosine pulse 2: raised cosine pulse AND draw the summation of the pulses rather than individual pulses
  % #2 channel bits as input to the channel
\begin{frame}{Intersymbol Interference (ISI) Channel}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[boundingBox](0,0) rectangle ++(11,6);     % Set the BB
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}{
      \node[channelModule,scale=1.4] at (4.5,5)(channel){Channel};
    }{
      \node[channelModule,inner sep=0.3cm] at (4.5,5)(channel){ISI Channel};
    }
    \draw[<-](channel.180)--node[above,signalLabel]{Channel bits $\mathbf{c}_k$}++(-4,0);
    \draw[->](channel.0)--node[above,signalLabel]{Readback waveform $\mathbf{r}_k$}++(5,0);
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{ % Only try to draw the user bits and waveforms if a set of bits (#2) has been provided by the caller
      \userBits{(channel.south west)+(-3.0,0.0)}{channelBit}{#2} % Draw the user bits at the channel input
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{ % if equal to 1, then draw the separated pulses
        \drawIndividualWaveforms{(channel.south east)+(2.5,-0.25)}{channelWaveform}{#2} % Draw the waveform consisting of the individual components of the impulse response
      }{                          % if equal to 2 then draw the combined waveform.
        \drawCombinedWaveforms{(channel.south east)+(2.5,-0.25)}{channelWaveform}{#2} % Draw the waveform consisting of the summation of the components of the impulse response
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}}
\channelSubFrame{1}{}
\channelSubFrame{1}{a/+/1}
\channelSubFrame{1}{a/+/1,b/--/2}
\channelSubFrame{1}{a/+/1,b/--/2,c/--/3}
\channelSubFrame{1}{a/+/1,b/--/2,c/--/3,d/+/4}
\channelSubFrame{1}{a/+/1,b/--/2,c/--/3,d/+/4,e/--/5}
\channelSubFrame{1}{a/+/1,b/--/2,c/--/3,d/+/4,e/--/5,f/+/6}
\end{document}
```

I am able to plot multiple pulses on the same plot, but I am not able to plot the summation of these pulses together into a single waveform. I tried putting the \foreach loop inside the \addplot as shown in the 
\drawCombinedWaveforms command I tried to define, but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: It is not too difficult to draw the sum of functions, you need only to accumulate the summands, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508968/194703. However, your approach nests `tikzpicture`s. Please don't!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to accumulate the functions. Notice that one should *not* nest `tikzpicure`s, and there is absolutely no need for that, you can use the `shift` key to move the axes. Other than that there are several things that could be changed such as the pgfplots compatibility version.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes.arrows,shapes.geometric,calc,decorations.markings,patterns}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Draw the user bits 
\newcommand{\userBits}[3]{
  % #1 the location west anchor of the bit array
  % #2 a base label identifying this set of bits, eg: userBits or parityBits
  % #3 the contents of the foreach loop that creates the bit array eg: a/1/0,b/1/1,c/0/2
  % The first component is part of the label for the node box created that holds the bit
  % The second component is the contents of the box that is written onto the page
  % The third component is needed for compatibility with the drawIndividualWaveforms function
  %                     it is not used in this function, but should still be there for compatibility.
  \coordinate(O) at ($#1$);
  \foreach\i/\j/\k in {#3}{
    \node [bitBox,fill=blue!15] at (O)(#2\i){\j};
    \coordinate(O) at (#2\i.0);
  }
}


\newcommand{\drawIndividualWaveforms}[3]{
  % #1 the location of the plot of individual waveforms
  % #2 a label for this node
  % #3 the contents of the for loop holding 3 components such as a/+/0:
  %    first component is a sublabel for this particular bit
  %    second component is the value of the bit either + or -
  %    third component is a k index indicating the delay of this wave pulse.
  \begin{axis} [shift={($#1+(0,-1cm)$)},axis lines =left,
      width=6cm, height=2.7cm,
      xtick=\empty,xticklabel=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,
      axis x line = middle,
      ymin=-1.1, ymax=1.1,
      xmin=0, xmax=7,
    ]
    \foreach\i/\j/\k in{#3}{
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\j}{+}}{
        \addplot[domain=\k-1:\k+1,
          samples=21,] {exp(-(x-\k)*(x-\k)*4)}; %{0.5*cos(180*x-180*\k)+0.5};
      }{
        \addplot[domain=\k-1:\k+1,
          samples=21,] {-exp(-(x-\k)*(x-\k)*4)}; %{-0.5*cos(180*x-180*\k)-0.5};
      }
    }
  \end{axis}      
  }
\newcommand{\drawCombinedWaveforms}[3]{
  % #1 the location of the plot of individual waveforms
  % #2 a label for this node
  % #3 the contents of the for loop holding 3 components such as a/+/0:
  %    first component is a sublabel for this particular bit
  %    second component is the value of the bit either + or -
  %    third component is a k index indicating the delay of this wave pulse.
  \begin{axis} [shift={($#1+(0,-1cm)$)},axis lines =left,
      width=6cm, height=2.7cm,
      xtick=\empty,xticklabel=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,
      axis x line = middle,
      ymin=-1.1, ymax=1.1,
      xmin=0, xmax=7,
    ]
    \def\k{5}
    \def\myf{0}
    \foreach\i/\j/\k in {#3}{
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\j}{+}}{
        \xdef\myf{\myf+exp(-(x-\k)*(x-\k)*4)}
        }{
        \xdef\myf{\myf-exp(-(x-\k)*(x-\k)*4)}
        }
      }
    \addplot[domain=0:7,samples=101,color=blue]{\myf};
  \end{axis}      
  }
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\tikzset{>=stealth,
  signalLabel/.style={text centered,font=\scriptsize,above,align=center},
  boundingBox/.style={use as bounding box},
  channelModule/.style={scale=.7,draw,top color=blue!30,align=center,inner sep=0.25cm,minimum height=1.2cm,node distance=0.75cm,minimum width=1.5cm},
  bitBox/.style={anchor=180,draw,font=\scriptsize,inner sep=0,minimum width=0.33cm,minimum height=0.4cm}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\channelSubFrame}[2]{
  % Create a subframe for the animation demonstrating the parity check ENCODING process
  % #1 Flag for the contenst of the channel box. 0: Channel. 1: Raised cosine pulse 2: raised cosine pulse AND draw the summation of the pulses rather than individual pulses
  % #2 channel bits as input to the channel
\begin{frame}{Intersymbol Interference (ISI) Channel}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[boundingBox](0,0) rectangle ++(11,6);     % Set the BB
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}{
      \node[channelModule,scale=1.4] at (4.5,5)(channel){Channel};
    }{
      \node[channelModule,inner ysep=0.7cm,inner xsep=0.3cm] at (4.5,5)(channel){ISI Channel};
    }
    \draw[<-](channel.180)--node[above,signalLabel]{Channel bits $\mathbf{c}_k$}++(-4,0);
    \draw[->](channel.0)--node[above,signalLabel]{Readback waveform $\mathbf{r}_k$}++(5,0);
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{ % Only try to draw the user bits and waveforms if a set of bits (#2) has been provided by the caller
      \userBits{(channel.south west)+(-3.0,0.0)}{channelBit}{#2} % Draw the user bits at the channel input
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{ % if equal to 1, then draw the separated pulses
        \drawIndividualWaveforms{(channel.south east)+(2.5,-0.25)}{channelWaveform}{#2} % Draw the waveform consisting of the individual components of the impulse response
      }{                          % if equal to 2 then draw the combined waveform.
        \drawCombinedWaveforms{(channel.south east)+(2.5,-0.25)}{channelWaveform}{#2} % Draw the waveform consisting of the summation of the components of the impulse response
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}}
\channelSubFrame{1}{}
\channelSubFrame{1}{a/+/1}
\channelSubFrame{1}{a/+/1,b/--/2}
\channelSubFrame{0}{a/+/1,b/--/2}
\channelSubFrame{1}{a/+/1,b/--/2,c/--/3}
\channelSubFrame{0}{a/+/1,b/--/2,c/--/3}
\channelSubFrame{1}{a/+/1,b/--/2,c/--/3,d/+/4}
\channelSubFrame{0}{a/+/1,b/--/2,c/--/3,d/+/4}
\channelSubFrame{1}{a/+/1,b/--/2,c/--/3,d/+/4,e/--/5}
\channelSubFrame{0}{a/+/1,b/--/2,c/--/3,d/+/4,e/--/5}
\channelSubFrame{1}{a/+/1,b/--/2,c/--/3,d/+/4,e/--/5,f/+/6}
\channelSubFrame{0}{a/+/1,b/--/2,c/--/3,d/+/4,e/--/5,f/+/6}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply SC. I'm trying to use your proposed method to build a similar table inside a \newcommand. I am using the \begin{tabular}{ccc} \end{tabular} environment. The contents of the table are passed in as the inputs to a \foreach loop. If I try to put the foreach loop directly inside the \begin{tabular} environment, it fails. However if I try to build a \mytable macro using a foreach loop similar to what you've done here, it also fails when I try to include the end-of-line delimiter \\ that goes to a new line. Do you have any suggestion on how to overcome this?

Comment: @Chah Please as a separate question in which you explicitly show what you are doing. From your comment I cannot infer the code that you are trying. And if this solves your original question, could you please consider accepting it?